# What is the reason for an unhandled win32 exception in an installer program?

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-2008, winapi, numpy

I got the following message:

`An unhandled win32 exception occurred in numpy-1.5.0-sse3.exe [3324].`

The exception occurred in the Numpy installer for Python 2.7---I have the latter on the machine.

When I clicked "Yes" for using the selected debugger, I got the following message:

`The Application Data folder for Visual Studio could not be created.`

I don't have admin privileges.

Is this the reason for the exception, or is there some other reason?

Comment: If a folder couldn't be created then that sounds like a no admin privileges problem to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the reason for the exception.  Instead, when you tried to debug the original problem, you encountered a problem with Visual Studio.  The Visual Studio error is resolved in the following manner:

Check your registry under the following path:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
```

Under there should be an entry for AppData.  The key value should be like so:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming
```

If it isn't, change it to the above value and your program should now work.

As for the original error, we really don't have enough information to comment intelligently.